# How to do query with timestamp?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this table:

```
id (int)
name (varchar)
insert (timestamp)
```

An example row is this:

```
14, John, 2010-02-25 01:48:36
```

In this table I have 1 million of rows and I want to know how many rows have been inserted in each day. So I want something like this:

```
2010-02-25 153
2010-02-24 98
2010-02-23 219
2010-02-22 127
...
```

What query do I have to do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(`insert`) AS day, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY day
```

Note that days that have no rows will *not* be represented in the result set.